# Word for when something makes something else seems smaller in a relative manner

Tags: american-english, british-english, metaphors, popular-refrains, simile

I'm trying to think of a word that is somehow alluding me.

Imagine two people are speaking loudly, but then a third person begins shouting even louder. The third persons voice has made the other two voices seem smaller and less significant, maybe even more cowering.

You could say his voice SOMETHING their voices.

It's not diminished, or dominate. There is another phrase or word I cannot remember.

Comment: "Elude" is to escape from you, like this word is. "Allude" is to indirectly call attention to something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the **title** of the question (which uses the word "smaller") I would have suggested *dwarf*:

**dwarf (verb):** Cause to seem small or insignificant in comparison. (from [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dwarf])[1](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dwarf).

While I have, on occasion, read about a "big" and maybe even a "small" voice, those wouldn't be my first choice of words.  I'm more used to hearing voice described as "loud" or "soft."  In that sense I don't like my own answer. I'm submitting it anyway since the question is specifically looking for words about relative size (rather than relative loudness).

Comment: +1 "dwarfed" fits the title question perfectly. What _is_ the difference between volume and size, BTW?

Comment: @Conrado: I wasn't clear.  I didn't stop to think that volume has two meanings. 
 One has to do with the amount of space occupied (and is related to size). The other has to do with loudness (e.g, the volume control on a radio). I was thinking of the 2nd meaning.  I'll edit the reply to clarify, thanks for pointing out the conflicting meanings.

Answer (score 12):

The general question is answered by the metaphorical sense of **eclipse**.

> **eclipse** verb (IMPORTANCE)   [ T often passive ]
>
> ...
>
> (2) *to make another person or thing seem much less important, good, or*
>   *famous*:
>
> - The economy has eclipsed all other issues during this election campaign.

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/eclipse)]

For sounds, it is not a particularly good metaphor.

You'd probably use **drown/ed out**.

> **drown out** Verb [[multi-word] [transitive]] (idiomatic)
>
> *To cover, obscure, or hide by being louder than.*
>
> - He uses the music to drown out other noises around him.

[[Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/drown-out)]

Comment: yes, drowned out is what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> "It's not diminished, or dominate. There is another phrase or word I cannot remember."

Since you want something that applies to voices, and is similar to the two words you mention, I would use [**overpower**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overpower):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : to affect with overwhelming intensity
>   // the stench *overpowered* us

In other words:

> You could say his voice *overpowered* their voices.

---

Most likely the reason you would have thought of it as a phrase is because it's composed of two individual words *over* and *power*.

It also applies equally to every sense, as well as other things, so it can be used in almost any situation.

Answer (score 2):

How about **overwhelm**? From M-W:

> **[overwhelm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overwhelm)**: to overcome by superior force or numbers

From Dictionary.com:

> **[overwhelm](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/overwhelm?s=t)**: to load, heap, treat, or address with an overpowering or excessive amount of anything

Your example:

> *You could say his voice **overwhelmed** their voices.*

Comment: Though we appreciate your contribution, I don't think that example sounds like a correct sentence from a native speaker.

Comment: @piono It is a correct sentence from a native speaker.

Comment: I was not clear. What I meant is that the word, as used, doesn't match any dictionary definition I could find, though it would work if you were talking about waves or something else more substantial than sound.

Comment: @piojo Thanks for the clarification. Dictionaries doesn't always capture the many possible meanings and uses of words. How about this from Dictionary.com: to load, heap, treat, or address with an overpowering or excessive amount of anything.

Comment: I agree with you about dictionaries, though in this case I side with the dictionaries. I think they are capturing the sense that "overwhelming" is a kind of attack (intentional or not), and you wouldn't attack a sound. But I have no authority upon which to base my opinion. I would also never "overwhelm my coffee with sugar", though that would be right according to the Dictionary.com definition. It's hard to capture meaning.

Comment: @piojo Fair enough, but I see no problem with one sound overwhelming another, one taste overwhelming another, one smell overwhelming another, the effect of X overwhelming the effect of Y, et cetera. To go a little further, one might say that the effect of the sound waves emitted by X on the ear drums of those present overwhelmed the effects of the sound waves emitted by Y on the ear drums of those present, which one might edit with no loss of clarity to "X's voice overwhelmed Y's voice." Thanks for the exchange.

Comment: @piojo One more thought. *Swamp* has issues similar to those of *overwhelm*. According to M-W, one meaning is *to overwhelm numerically or by an excess of something*. So, would it be correct or incorrect to say *X's voice swamped Y's*?

Comment: @piojo Good thought.

Comment: In some of your examples, it seems like _overshadow_ might be more appropriate. To my ears, that is the word you're looking for, particularly in the "et cetera" examples you gave. However, those examples are easy to search for, and "overwhelms the effect of" is more popular than _overshadows_. I would say the usage of _overwhelm_ swamps _overshadow_. To answer your question with another question, can an uncountable object _swamp_? And if not, is my sentence okay because of the implication of numerical comparison? (I made a mistake and had to delete/rewrite)

Comment: @piojo We're going to have to end out exchange. Not completely sure, but the answer to your first question is probably *no*, and the answer to your second question is probably *yes*. In saying that "The usage of *overwhelm* swamps [that of] *overshadow*", you are implying that *usage* is measured by the number of references, say. By the same token, in saying that "X's voice overwhelmed Y's voice", I am implying that *voice* is measured by the amplitude of the associated sound waves.

Answer (score 1):

> **Undermine:** to make someone less confident, less powerful, or less likely to succeed, or to make something weaker, often gradually.
>
> Examples:
>
> - The president has accused two cabinet members of working secretly to undermine his position/him.
> - Criticism just undermines their confidence. 
>     — [Cambridge English dictionary](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/undermine)

You could also say *outshine, nerf (v), outstrip or transcend* - depends on the context.

Comment: To undermine is to act against someone.